# Finding a suitable data structure for deletion from both lists

Tags: database, performance, algorithm, data-structures

This might be deleted, since involves idea sharing which is not quite allowed in stack overflow, but still before that if I could get any ideas from solid programmers, it will be a win situation for me

Assume that you have a class **Student**, stored in the database, and this class has a list property called **favoriteTeachers**. This list constantly gets updated by the system and involves the id of teachers.

You also have a class **Teacher**, also stored in database and likewise has a list property **favouriteStudents**. It is again updated constantly and involves the id's of students.

In our system, when a student calls a function (let's say **notMyFavoriteTeacher**), our system has to apply the changes below;

1. Delete the given teacher's id from favouriteTeacher list
2. Delete the student's id from given teacher's favouriteStudent list

I've tried to consider the number of rows updated could exhaust the database so instead of mapping the students with their favorite teachers in a separate table as **user_id, teacher_id**, instead I created a column and stored a string which contains the teachers id's separated by comma. (Ex: "1,2,14,4,25"). Same applied for the **teacher** as well.

However when we call this function, we also face another problem. In order for this operation to be done, you need to convert the string to list, find the element by linear search and later on delete, and later on convert list to string and push back to db. And you have to do the other operation for the **teacher** class as well. If we **did not** apply the string method, deletion would be easier but since we would be handling deletion and addition operations for like 2k times a day, i did not think it would be **feasible** to use separate tables.

I wanted to ask in order to decrease the number of operations, could a data structure be chosen such that it would increase the **efficiency?**

Comment: This is one of these micro-"optimizations" that turn out to be slowdowns at the end. RDBMSs are good at dealing with lots of rows, just make sure that you have all the applicable indexes in place. What you are trying to do creates problems in many important areas (referential integrity, normalization). These problems will be harder to fix than any performance issues that you may encounter doing it the correct way (with a separate table).

Comment: Are the lists you describe two distinct lists (e.g. can a student have a teacher as a favorite where the teacher does not have that student as a favorite)? I'm asking, because the delete operation suggests otherwise.

Comment: No. By the system if a student has a teacher as his/her favourite, than teacher will have him/her as a favorite student as well.

Comment: So why do you need two delete operations? One mapping table, wich contains that relation (e.g. favorites[student_id, teacher_id]), would suffice.  Deleting the appropriate row from that table would remove the relation for boths students and teachers.

Comment: I am certain I have had favorite teachers who did not, in turn, favor me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing an relation as an array in a single column is a violation of [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), and should not be done without good reason.  Although various forms of denormalization *may* result in increased efficiency in some cases, I don't see this case being one of those.  What's worse, you'll get no help from the database in enforcing referential integrity.  And some operations will result in guaranteed row scans: When deleting a teacher, you will have to examine every row of every student to remove the teacher from each student's favorite list.  Same goes for deleting a student.

Relational Databases are designed and built to link rows to other rows.  You need a very good reason to keep them from doing what they're design to do.  You should go ahead and design a proper relational schema, and only if actual measurement shows that it is too slow should you worry about its performance.

Comment: Thaks so much for the creative answer. It's been helpful. I'll go ahead and probably take another look my schema, however even though I apply it the normal way I do not think it will increase the running time by any change because still it will come down to O(n)

Comment: @Ali, With indices in place, many operations are much better than O(n).  Indeed, that's the whole point of having indices.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't understand your choice of storing ids of favorite teachers/students as comma separated strings, because either in the case of comma separated values or in case of a table with studentId, teacherId structure, you do exactly 2 row updates/deletes (first in the favoriteTeachers table, second in the favoriteStudent table).

But one way of optimizing performance given your current data structure would be keeping the comma separated strings sorted. I mean from the very formation of rows, keep your comma separated ids like "1, 5, 7, 15". This way, if you convert it to a list, you could perform binary search and it would take Log(n) time instead of n.

Comment: Thanks for the productive answer. You cleared some stuff I had problem with.

Comment: the way to say thank you in Stack Overflow is voting up the answer

Comment: The way I say thank you is making a comment. If it's really helpful then vote up the answer. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are losing all the benefits provided by any RDBMS by storing it as a list of strings. Create a separate table with Student_id and favorite teacher_id. Apply filtering conditions (either for student or for teacher) before joining it to main tables.